# Android: How to create an expanding list like in Youtube app

Tags: android, list, listview, youtube, expandablelistview

I was looking at the Android YouTube app from Nov 2012, I they have a "list" like view which shows the related videos to the current video. If they click on the "more" part, it loads more below.

What I want to know is how they are implementing this screen al together. It doesn't seem like it is a standard ExpandableList in Android. But can someone maybe give some input?

I have done something similar by creating a LinearLayout and then adding more to the viewgroup as I create them. But then the problem is that they aren't managed by an adapter and the views are very static.

[image: YouTube Android app Related Videos list that grows.]